# how to insert multiple records in django?

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

```
def input_transaksi(request):    
    kode_pem = dict(request.POST)['kode_pem']
    nominal = dict(request.POST)['nominal']
    rincian = Transaksi(kode_pem=kode_pem,nominal=nominal)
    rincian.save()
```

**model.py**

```
class Transaksi(models.Model):
    nominal = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    kode_pem = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then I input data from this form

```
{% for t in trans %} #for looping form
    <from  method="post" action="{% url 'input_transaksi' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <input type="hidden" name="kode_pem">           
        <input type="hidden" name="nominal">
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

But I get this error:

```
Environment: Request Method: POST Request URL: http://localhost:8000/transaksi/input_transaksi

Django Version: 1.10.4 Python Version: 2.7.11 Installed Applications: ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'django.contrib.humanize',  'datapribadisiswa',  'riwayatsekolah',  'riwayatprestasi',  'dataguru',  'biaya_pendidikan',  'transaksi_kas', 'kodepembayaran',  'django_ajax',  'import_export'] Installed Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\siswa\transaksi_kas\views.py" in input_transaksi
  1213.     rincian.save()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  796.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  824.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  908.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  947.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1045.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1053.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  1006.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in prepare_value
  945.             value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  755.                                       prepared=False)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  747.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1832.         return int(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /transaksi/input_transaksi Exception Value: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: can you show your Transaksi model?

Comment: i've added my model @AbiWaqas

Comment: I think your nominal field is expecting an integer it is receiving list  because of for loop you are applying in our templates.U can use bulk create as @Robert has posted in the answer

Comment: i get this error  
bulk_create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kode_pem'

Answer (score 4):

HI you can use **bulk create** method.

This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are):

Refer the document [bulk-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: i got this error >bulk_create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kode_pem' @robert

Comment: @Gusan did you refer the document.

Comment: please refer the document,"rincian = Transaksi(kode_pem=kode_pem,nominal=nominal)
    rincian.save()" these lines are totally  wrong

Comment: i've changed it to this Transaksi.objects.bulk_create(nominal=nominal,kode_pem=kode_pem)

Comment: and get this error bulk_create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kode_pem' @robert

Comment: you cann't pass like that you need pass model instance

Comment: would you give the scripts?

Comment: can you look at official document they provide example

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: i use this script `Transaksi.objects.bulk_create([Transaksi(nominal=nominal),Transaksi(kode_pem=kode_pem),Transaksi(id_trans=1)]) `
but get this error `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`